# How do I create a new class to process two other classes in Java?

Tags: java, weka

I have two classes called "J48Tree" and "RandomTree". They are both subclasses of "AbstractTree".

"J48Tree" and "RandomTree" have a method called "graph()", other subclasses of "AbstractTree" don‘t have this method.

These classese above and the graph() method come from exsiting API. So I dont need to rewrite them.

Now I want to create a new class called “Visualization”. This class can receive "J48Tree" and "RandomTree" as genetic input data. And then run their "graph()" method.

I tried

```
public class Visualization  <T super J48Tree>
```

and

```
public class Visualization  <T extends AbstractTree>
```

But it doesn't work.

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a `Graphable` interface with the `graph()` method for your two classes and then use that in your `Visualization` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Florian says, you want to create an interface `Graphable` and make both `J48Tree` and `RandomTree` implement it.

```
public interface Graphable {
    void graph();
}

public class J48Tree extends AbstractTree implements Graphable {
    @Override
    public void graph() {
        // implementation
    }
}

public class RandomTree extends AbstractTree implements Graphable {
    @Override
    public void graph() {
        // implementation
    }
}

public class Visualization {
    private Graphable graphable;

    public void setGraphable(Graphable graphable) {
        this.graphable = graphable;
    }

    public void graph() {
        this.graphable.graph();
    }
}
```

Then, you can set the `Graphable` implementation on `Visualization` class by calling `setGraphable`.

**EDIT**

From your comment I understand you are not capable of making neither `J48Tree` nor `RandomTree` implement the `Graphable` interface (that's the only change on the classes you have to make). In this case, you should 'wrap' an instance of each class into another class, a wrapper, that implements `Graphable`.

```
public interface Graphable {
    void graph();
}

public class J48TreeWrapper implements Graphable {
    private final J48Tree j48Tree;

    public J48TreeWrapper(J48Tree j48Tree) {
        this.j48Tree = j48Tree;
    }

    @Override
    public void graph() {
        this.j48Tree.graph();
    }
}

public class RandomTreeWrapper implements Graphable {
    private final RandomTree randomTree;

    public RandomTreeWrapper(RandomTree andomTree) {
        this.randomTree = randomTree;
    }

    @Override
    public void graph() {
        this.randomTree.graph();
    }
}

public class Visualization {
    private Graphable graphable;

    public void setGraphable(Graphable graphable) {
        this.graphable = graphable;
    }

    public void graph() {
        this.graphable.graph();
    }
}
```

Now, you will first have to create an instance of `J48TreeWrapper` that 'wraps' a `J48Tree`, and then you call `setGraphable` using it (same with `RandomTreeWrapper`).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    J48TreeWrapper wrapper = new J48TreeWrapper(new J48Tree());
    Visualization visualization = new Visualization();
    visualization.setGraphable(wrapper);
    visualization.graph();
}
```

Comment: Thx. The "J48Tree","RandomTree" "AbstractTree"  classes and the graph() method come from existing API.  The "J48Tree","RandomTree" already have the graph() method in API. So I dont need to rewrite them. What should I do then?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the strategy design pattern:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm

Look apt for the scenario you mentioned, since the behavior(method) need to be decided on runtime based on input object passed.